# ARRAYFORMULA not populating down as expected

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a table which shows the distance between point A and multiple point B's.
Point B is listed as a series of columns (Scout groups: 104th Portsmouth, 2nd Portsmouth, etc.).

From each row, I identify the 3 closest points to Point A (by finding the 3 smallest distances).

I use INDEX to extract the column number for each (for example, the smallest) and return the group name from the column header in Row 1.

I want to use an ARRAYFORMULA because the number of rows in the table will change over time.
The problem is, it only returns a single answer and does not populate down the column as expected.
I have a similar problem with the find a minimum formula in cell R2

My latest attempt (in cell V2) is

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX($A$1:$P$1,,MIN(IF($A2:$P=R2,COLUMN(A:P)))))
```

My latest attempt (in cell R2) is

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORTN(TRANSPOSE(A2:P2),1,0,1,TRUE))
```

- $A$1:$P$1 are the column headers - the Scout Group names (point B)
- R2 is the cell containing the calculated smallest distance from the row (that I want to lookup).
- $A2:$P is the range to search for the value in R2.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK2dv.png)

I expect the ARRAYFORMULA to populate down to the last row.
I have searched (and searched and searched) for a solution, trying many different approaches - all without success.  So... it's time to ask for some help.

[Example spreadsheet with data and formula](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/174fapZo25Mxslc14j1BP2BBvaeCZAF--xW1u2TCd-hA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I think this gets the answers you're looking for (change end range as needed)

R2:

`=byrow(A2:P25, LAMBDA(row, ARRAYFORMULA(SORTN(transpose(row),1,0,1,TRUE))))`

V2:

`=byrow(R2:R25, LAMBDA(row, ArrayFormula(INDEX($A$1:$P$1,,MIN(IF($A2:$P=row,COLUMN(A:P)))))))`